# How can I get my JQuery UI menu position to always fit on screen and open to the right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, position

I'm trying to create a JQuery menu that:

1. Always opens its children to the right
2. Always flips its position where required so that it never
   disappears off the bottom of the screen.

*i.e.* Something like this...

[image]

I expected the following would work...

```
    $('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
         position: {
                my: "right top",
                at: "left top"
         }
    });
```

...but it only seems to work for the first child. The second child appears to the left of it ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/1/)).

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
    "position": { my: "left top", at: "right top" }
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Uqz/

To tweak the behaviour of the child items, check the jQuery UI position documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

When a child collides with the window border, it will flip by default.